# How to sort email addresses from google forms to one unique email?

Tags: google-sheets

Today I created a google form that saves automatic results to google sheets.

[image: Image 1]

The idea is that I send e-mail correspondence, but sometimes there are jokers who enter a different age, name, but the same e-mail. I would like to sort this from the results obtained into another sheet called "sort", people who are over 23 years of age.

I created the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(ask!A:D;"Select * Where D>=23"))
```

And it working correct.

[image]

Now how to add options to the formula already created above, so that it shows only one email address so that they do not duplicate each other? (Regardless of the name or age column ...)
I would like it to look like this in its final form:

[image]

Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

perhaps try:

```
=UNIQUE(Ask!B2:C)
```

or try:

```
=SORTN(Ask!A2:D, 9^9, 2, 2, 0)
```